# Eventlisteners in DataTables refuse to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I fail to make a checkbox do a simple alert like I try here:
https://jsfiddle.net/2n3dyLhh/5/
The problem is datatables (or how I use it) because when I do not include the library the listeners work perfectly.

The checkbox is embedded in a databales colum. Why does this fail?

```
<table id="eventsTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Checkbox
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkall" />
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox1"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Airi Satou</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox5" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox6" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox7" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox8" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox9" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sonya Frost</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox10" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jena Gaines</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox11" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox12" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    "columns": [null, {
        "orderable": false
    }]
});
$('#eventsTable').DataTable();

});
$("#checkall").on('click', function () {
     $('#eventsTable').DataTable()
        .column(1)
        .nodes()
        .to$()
        .find('input[type=checkbox]')
        .prop('checked', this.checked);
});

$("#checkbox12").on('click', function () {
     alert('it works');
});
$("#checkbox1").on('click', function () {
     alert('it works');
});
alert('one can do alerts in jfiddle');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the click handlers does not work because some of the rows are hidden by dataTables at the time you are assigning the handlers.

So you must use a delegated handler that assign click handlers to the checkboxes as they appear in the DOM. Besides that, you dont have to write a click handler for each and every checkbox; you can reduce it to one handler only and in that handler do whatever you want according to what checkbox that was clicked.

```js
$("#eventsTable").on('click', '[type="checkbox"]', function () {
   alert('checkbox #'+$(this).attr('id')+' clicked'); 
});
```

forked fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/s4z01p0z/**

Answer (score 0):

You try below code

```
$('body').on('click', '#checkbox1', function () {
        alert('it works');
});
```